# How to implement custom HTTP header RESTKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I'm using RESTKit to implement a GET request and with that request I want to have a custom http header. In order for the GET request to get the required data, I need to send up a token (as a variable) which I have in the header. However, when I look in the console for a response, it gives me a 401 status code, meaning that the website is not getting the custom http header. What exactly am I doing wrong that causes the custom header to not work.

Here is my code:

```
NSIndexSet *statusCodeSet = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful);
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://foo.com/foo/:foo_number/providers/find?name=%@&location=%@", nameIDTextField.text, locationTextField.text];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Here is my custom header code
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:url];
    [objectManager.HTTPClient setDefaultHeader:@"Auth-Token" value:[[self userAuthTokenMethod] userAuthToken]];
    //End of custom header code

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"Stuff Here ==> %@", connection);
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[MappingProvider tokenMapping]
                                                                                       pathPattern:@"/v2/styles"
                                                                                           keyPath:@"data"
                                                                                       statusCodes:statusCodeSet];
    NSURLRequest *doctorRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:doctorRequest
                                                                        responseDescriptors:@[responseDescriptor]];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
    {
        NSLog(@"Mapping Results ==> %@", mappingResult.array);
    }
    failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
    {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", operation.HTTPRequestOperation.responseString);
    }];

    [operation start];
```

Edit:

Here is the part of the error log:

```
2013-08-01 22:42:58.547 Empyrean[78461:5803] E restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:576 Object request failed: Underlying HTTP request 
operation failed with error: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 401"
```

If you find any other problems with the code, please feel free to point them out.

Comment: To set a pair key/value in the header with restkit it's just like you did, with `setDefaultHeader:value:` of your objectManager's client. Maybe the problem is somewhere else. Please, post the log os the restkit with the request/response data. In the log, you shoulb be able to see if the header is been sending in the request.

Comment: Turn on RK logging, by setting `RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);` and check if your header is indeed missing

Comment: I added part of the log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably fix your 401-problem most easily by using a `NSMutableURLRequest` like so:

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *doctorRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [doctorRequest setValue:[[self userAuthTokenMethod] userAuthToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Auth-Token"];
```

Apart from that: The `request`, `objectManager` and `connection` objects are not really used in that part of the code. And it probably would be best to set the header field by default for all requests as you tried with the objectManager. But then you need to get the HTTPClient of the objectManager to create your request for you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting the header on the object managers HTTP client and then not using the object manager, because you're creating your URL request explicitly and then an operation to run it. Choose 1 of the 2 options and stick with it. If you create the request yourself then you also need to add the headers to it.